# How to scan barcode with a phone (iOS and Android) to a website?

Tags: jquery, android, ios, jquery-mobile

I whant to do a webbapp in jQuery Mobile and i whant to have a input field where i whant a barcode scanner app to scann a barcodes and insert the value to this input field.

I whant it to work good in both iOS and Android, in Android i have found that zxing barcode scanner have a funktion that you send the user to a url with a calback url to so the app starts and after scan the barcode the app knows where to redirect to.

This is not a good solution for my app but if i dont find any other solution maybe need to try it.

But how to do it in iOS?

Comment: there are gazillion of apps for both iPhone and Android phones and I'd be amazed if you could launch them from a Web Browser, especially, because the user may not even have any of them installed

Comment: Any software in particular? I just have a form on a webpage and I want to feed a textbox with the code scanned from the barcode from a mobile device....